Equivalence Between Polar Coordinates and Cartesian Coordinates?
I am trying to better understand the relationship between Cartesian Coordinates and Polar Coordinates.
Here is what I understand:
When going from Cartesian Coordinates $(x, y)$ to Polar Coordinates $(r, \theta)$, the transformation is given by (I can draw a circle and use trigonometry to get these relationships):
$$
x = r \cos(\theta) \\
y = r \sin(\theta)
$$
The Jacobian matrix $J$ of this transformation contains all the first order partial derivatives:
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -r\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of the Jacobian matrix, $\text{det}(J)$, is calculated as:
$$
\text{det}(J) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} - \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} = r\cos^2(\theta) + r\sin^2(\theta) = r
$$
Here is where my confusion starts:
The above analysis supposedly gives us this classic relationship:
$$
dx \, dy = \text{det}(J) \, dr \, d\theta = r dr d\theta
$$
I am confused as to how the above the analysis implies that $dx \, dy = \text{det}(J) \, dr \, d\theta = r dr d\theta$ is true.
I understand that the Jacobian matrix  contains all the first order partial derivatives of the transformation. These partial derivatives describe small changes in the variable of interest.
But I don't understand:

Why does the presence of all these derivatives in the same matrix relate the change/equivalence between the two coordinate systems?
Why the determinant of the Jacobian matrix gives us the factor by which the transformation changes areas?

Can someone please help me out here?

It seems to me that your problem has nothing to do with polar coordinates, but with the general statement $dx , dy = \text{det}(J) , du , dv$

Intuition: $J$ is a linear transformation that describes how an infinitesimal region of $(r,\theta)$ coordinate space (say, a rectangle of sides $dr,d\theta$) transforms to an infinitesimal region of $(x,y)$ coordinate space (say, a parallelogram). The determinant is the scaling factor of area (or volume in general dimensions). (Normally symbols such as $dr,d\theta$ only make sense inside an integral, but they can be formalized in terms of differential forms, where the determinant naturally appears.)

@ jjagmath: when you put it in those words...I suppose you are correct...

@ arkeet: thank you for the clarifications ... I read some articles which showed why $dxdy = rdrd\theta$ is true from a pure geometry perspective (i.e. does not involve the determinant at all) ... but I am still not sure how to understand the relevance of the determinant in this equation ... can you please help me out ?

@wulasa it is not so hard to show that for any matrix, the determinant tells you how areas of parallelograms are changed. This is an infinitesimal version of that, you could say.

@ malady: I have never heard of this interpretation before (I am an engineering student) - could you please expand a bit on this in an answer if you have time?

See here & here.

This question is similar to: What does it mean to multiply differentials?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (Comment text is site boilerplate.)

If you want an explanation in the context of calculus, this is a mere consequence of the chain rule, which is applied many times due to the change of coordinates, with all the computations being somehow gathered together inside a matrix determinant for the sake of clarity. In a way, it can be deduced informally but straightforwardly with the help of a vectorial notation such as
$$
\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}(x,y) = \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}\mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}(r,\theta) = \det J \,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
But I guess this is not the explanation you are looking for, that is why here is a geometric approach.
Let's recall that your coordinate systems parametrize a surface $S$. This surface may be described conventionally by its normal vector field (cf. Gauss map). How is it constructed ? At a given point $p \in S$, the normal vector is by definition orthogonal to the surface $S$, and more precisely to its tangent plane at $p$. The latter is spanned by the tangential vectors  $\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial\theta}$, where $\vec{r} = (x,y)$. Note that they corresponds to the columns of the Jacobian matrix. In consequence, the normal vector is given by the cross product of the tangential vectors, i.e. $\vec{n} = \frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial\theta} \times \frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial r}$, while its norm represents the area of the parallelogram formed by the tangential vectors due to the properties of the cross product $-$ it has to be highlighted that this parallelogram doesn't belong to the surface $S$ but lies in the tangent plane. Yet, in $\Bbb{R}^2$, one has $\|\vec{n}\| = \left|\det\left(\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial r}\right)\right|$, which is nothing else than the Jacobian $|\det J|$.
Now, this reasoning is also valid with an infinitesimal area. Moreover, since the surface element $\mathrm{d}S = \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ is arbitrarily small, it can be identified with the associated parallelogram in the tangent plane, whose sides are given by $\mathrm{d}\vec{x}$ and $\mathrm{d}\vec{y}$, hence the normal vector $\mathrm{d}\vec{S} = \mathrm{d}\vec{x} \times \mathrm{d}\vec{y} = \vec{n}(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \vec{n}(r,\theta)\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$, where the last equality corresponds to the change of parametrization of the surface $S$ towards polar coordinates. Now, taking the norm of this expression in order to recover the area element, we get $\mathrm{d}S = \|\vec{n}\|\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta = |\det J|\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$.
This treatment can be extended to higher-dimensional spaces; then, the cross product is replaced by the exterior product and the volume element $\mathrm{d}x_1 \cdots \mathrm{d}x_n$ is interpreted as a differential form.
